# "Signature" user field not appearing in list of user fields

Tags: 7, users, entities

I have the Drupal core *Signature* field that appears on the user edit page; it doesn't seem to show up as a field on the *Manage Display* tab when I go to re-order and group the fields on the edit page.

Does anyone know how I can get this field to appear in the field list with the rest of the fields so I can group and reorder it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it doesn't appear that you can put it in the field list directly and drag and drop it around as the user module only exposes the account and timezone in its [hook_fields_extra_fields()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_extra_fields/7), you certainly can move it around "manually" in a [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) in a custom module, eg something along these lines:

```
function YOURMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  switch ($form_id) {

    case 'user_profile_form':

      drupal_set_message('<pre>' . print_r($form, TRUE) . '</pre>'); // to see what you have to work with

      $form['signature_settings']['#weight']='8';
      $form['field_my_second_custom_field']['#weight']='9';

      break;

    // other forms go here

  }

}
```

...which, if you had the following in your user:

[image]

...would create this in the edit form:

[image]

...eg, we moved the `#weight` around, which is what the drag and drop anchors do in the UI.

In this example, `user.module` initially creates the signature settings with a weight of 1, and then the custom fields with 7 and above, so, by changing the weight to 8 for the signature settings and the next field to 9, it puts it between those two fields.  Check out the [Drupal Form API and #weight](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#weightval) for more information on what this is all about.

If you click `show row weights` at `admin/config/people/accounts/fields` you can see this more directly:

[image]

**ADDITION:  Using Field Groups**

If you had it set up like this:

[image]

...and wanted to put the signature settings inside the "My Group" field group, you could do something like this:

```
function YOURMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  switch ($form_id) {

    case 'user_profile_form':

      $form['signature_settings']['#weight']='6';
      $form['field_my_second_custom_field']['#weight']='7';

      $form['#fieldgroups']['group_my_group']->children[]='signature_settings';
      $form['#group_children']['signature_settings'] = 'group_my_group';

      break;

    // other forms go here

  }

}
```

...which would produce this:

[image]

**YET MORE ADDITIONS:  Tab Groups**

If you want to put it in a tab group, eg:

[image]

...this will do it:

```
function YOURMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  switch ($form_id) {

    case 'user_profile_form':

      $form['signature_settings']['#weight']='6';
      $form['field_my_second_custom_field']['#weight']='7';

      // $form['#fieldgroups']['group_my_group']->children[]='signature_settings'; // apparently this isn't needed afterall
      $form['#group_children']['signature_settings'] = 'group_my_group';

      break;

    // other forms go here

  }

}
```

...which produces this:

[image]

Comment: I'm using [Field Group](https://drupal.org/project/field_group) (I failed to mention that in my post), but with your method I think I can still inject the right HTML to make the signature field appear in one of my tab groups. I'll give this a try, and accept if it works. Thanks! (And good job on the pictures - those helped a lot!)

Comment: I added some code to address field groups above and hope that helps out as well.

Comment: Actually, it's not that easy as you've probably noticed when the field group isn't just a plain fieldset, the tab title is wrong, but with some more hacking at it I am sure it can be made to work perfectly

Comment: Cool, thanks for the extra code. I'll definitely give this a try later and let you know if it works.

Comment: I think I finally got it :)

Comment: This worked PERFECTLY! I grouped all the fields that I couldn't group with Field UI into a tab group. THANK YOU! :)